# System call interception in linux-kernel module (kernel 3.5)

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I need to replace a standard system call (e.g. SYS_mkdir) with my own implementation.

As I read in some sources, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613301/loadable-kernel-module-programming-and-system-call-interception) on Stackoverflow, the `sys_call_table` is not exported symbol since kernel version `2.6`.

I tried the following code:

```
    #include <linux/module.h> 
    #include <linux/kernel.h> 
    #include <linux/unistd.h> 
    #include <asm/syscall.h> 

    int (*orig_mkdir)(const char *path); 

    ....

    int init_module(void) 
    { 
            orig_mkdir=sys_call_table[__NR_mkdir]; 
            sys_call_table[__NR_mkdir]=own_mkdir;  
            printk("sys_mkdir replaced\n"); 
            return(0); 
    } 

    ....
```

Unfortunately I receive compiler error:

```
 error: assignment of read-only location ‘sys_call_table[83]’
```

How can I replace the system call?

**EDIT:** Is there any solution without kernel patching?

Comment: try with type cast to `char*` then assign

Comment: may be [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/133982-cannot-modify-sys_call_table.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example) is helpful to you

Comment: There is no universal solution w/o patching.

Answer (score 8):

this works for me.

See
[Linux Kernel: System call hooking example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103315/linux-kernel-system-call-hooking-example)
and
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139406

```
asmlinkage long (*ref_sys_open)(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);
asmlinkage long new_sys_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
  return ref_sys_open(filename, flags, mode);
}

static unsigned long **aquire_sys_call_table(void)
{
  unsigned long int offset = PAGE_OFFSET;
  unsigned long **sct;

  while (offset < ULLONG_MAX) {
    sct = (unsigned long **)offset;

    if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *) sys_close) 
      return sct;

    offset += sizeof(void *);
  }
  print("Getting syscall table failed. :(");
  return NULL;
}


// Crazy copypasted asm stuff. Could use linux function as well...
// but this works and will work in the future they say.
static void disable_page_protection(void) 
{
  unsigned long value;
  asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r" (value));

  if(!(value & 0x00010000))
    return;

  asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" : : "r" (value & ~0x00010000));
}

static void enable_page_protection(void) 
{
  unsigned long value;
  asm volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r" (value));

  if((value & 0x00010000))
    return;

  asm volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" : : "r" (value | 0x00010000));
}


static int __init rootkit_start(void) 
{

  //Hide me

  print("loaded");

  if(!(sys_call_table = aquire_sys_call_table()))
    return -1;

  disable_page_protection(); 
  {
    ref_sys_open = (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long *)new_sys_open;
  }
  enable_page_protection();
  return 0;
}

static void __exit rootkit_end(void) 
{
  print("exiting");

  if(!sys_call_table) {
    return;
  }

  disable_page_protection();
  {
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long *)ref_sys_open;
  }
  enable_page_protection();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is a solution without patching/rebuilding the kernel. Use the [Kprobes](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/kprobes/index.html) infrastructure (or SystemTap).

This will allow you to place "probes" (functions) at any point(s) within the kernel, using a kernel module.

Doing similar stuff by modifying the sys_call_table is now prevented (it's read-only) & is considered a dirty hack! Kprobes/Jprobes/etc are a "clean" way to do so..Also, the documentation and [samples](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7/samples/kprobes/) provided in the kernel source tree is excellent (look under the kernel src tree- [Documentation/kprobes.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.7/Documentation/kprobes.txt)).

Comment: kprobes/systemtap won't let you *replace* the system call handler, but can supplement it / precede it.

Comment: Hey, kprobes uses patching :)

Comment: @fche: yes, i agree. The point was that the effect is similar..

@ IlyaMatveychikov: AFAIK, no, kprobes is an in-kernel feature; you don't need to apply any patch. Also, most distros have kprobes enabled..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused due to the fact that sys_call_table is read only. In order to avoid the error, before manipulating the sys_call_table, you have to make it writable as well. The kernel provides a function to achieve it. And that function is given as **set_mem_rw()**.

Just add the below code snippet before manipulating the sys_call_table

```
set_mem_rw((long unsigned int)sys_call_table,1);
```

In the exit function of the kernel module,please do not forget to revert back the sys_call_table back to read only.It can be achieved as below.

```
set_mem_ro((long unsigned int)sys_call_table,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to determine the location of sys_call_table. See [here](http://www.gadgetweb.de/linux/40-how-to-hijacking-the-syscall-table-on-latest-26x-kernel-systems.html).

Before writing into the just located system table, you have to make its memory pages writable. For that check [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/133982-cannot-modify-sys_call_table.html#post666831) and if that doesn't work, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6742086/479753).

Answer (score 0):

Use LSM infrustructure.

Look at LSM hooks `path_mkdir` or `inode_mkdir` for details. One question that needs to be solved is how to register your own LSM module while the system don't allow it explicitly. See the answer for details here:

[How can I implement my own hook function with LSM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428212/how-can-i-implement-my-own-hook-function-with-lsm)